# Grails 3 vs 4 performance, starting time and memory

Tags: performance, grails, grails3, micronaut, grails-4

The documentation of Grails 4 mentions an improvement in performance and starting time due to the micronaut parent context ( [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#micronautSupport) ).

Did anyone measure the improvement from Grails 3 to Grails 4? How does Grails 4 compare to Grails 3 in boot time, performance and memory consumption?

Comment: I asked a similar question "Should I consider Grails 4 over Micronaut?" Sadly it got downvoted, and eventually removed.
I can only guide you rather than answer, I have used Grails 2 & 3, Springboot and from my observations that they don't come any close to Micronaut, so it's very possible that the performance gains will be substantial for Grails 4.

Comment: An interesting question,  the answer to which will definitely influence whether I attempt an upgrade sooner than later.   Now it's released have you done any performance comparison ?

Comment: Still not, but I've head the framework gained at least fifteen seconds of startup time.

Comment: My experience so far,  with an app that took ~60 seconds to startup, now takes ~30.
Hot Reloading while developing has gone in favour of hot restarts,  which is somewhat of a drag as if you have anything considerable going on during bootstrapping this can quickly become time-consuming.  Although there are workarounds to use spring loaded directly which helps overcome this.

When running (in dev mode), this app is noticeably faster,    small apps that take < 10 seconds to start up aren't really an issue with hot-restarting, 

Summary: I'm happy upgrading and will upgrade all my apps to G4

Answer (score 1):

Writing an answer for the record. I recently upgraded a fairly sizeable grails 3 app (~150 domain classes) and noticed around 30% reduction in the boot time and 20-30% reduction in the memory footprint of the app. Hot restarting in Grails 4 is really annoying and wastes a lot of time for even small changes. I really miss the hot-swapping of grails 3. Other than that, it's worthwhile.

[This article](https://dev.to/erichelgeson/grails-4-upgrade-notes-3cja) gives some of the grails performance metrics comparison between grails 3.3.9 and 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just after upgrade from 3.3.14 to 4.0.12 I see 20% more CPU usage and request processing time on production.
Can be some non-optimal settings. But with simple framework upgrade I got a performance penalty
(150k unique visitors per day, 6Gb of memory).

In same time application use 30% less memory.

**UPDATE**:

performance issue caused by broken hibernate second level cache for classes with inheritance
https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1594

**UPDATE 1**:

After fix of cache issue I see CPU usage improvement. Grails4 use around 5-10% less CPU compare to grails 3.3.14

I think, upgrade to grails 4 recommended